# Integrating a function where the denominator is the square root of a second order polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration

Below is a problem I did. The answer I got differed from the book by a factor of $2$. An online calculator get the book's answer. I would like to know where I went wrong.

Problem:

Evalaute the following integral:
$$ \int \frac{dx}{ \sqrt{9x^2 - 6x + 5} } \,\, dx $$
Answer:

Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{dx } { 3 \sqrt{x^2 - \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) x + \frac{5}{9} } } \\
3I &= \int \frac{dx } { \sqrt{ \left( x - \frac{1}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) ^ 2 } } \\
u &= x - \frac{1}{3} \\
du &= dx \\
3I &= \int \frac{du } { \sqrt{ u^2 + \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) ^ 2 } } \\
u &= \left(  \frac{2}{3} \right) \tan \left( \theta \right)  \\
du &=  \left(  \frac{2}{3} \right) \sec^2 \left( \theta \right) \,\, d\theta \\
%
3I &= \int \frac{ \left(  \frac{2}{3} \right) \sec^2 \left( \theta \right) \,\, d\theta  }
 { \sqrt{ \left( \frac{4}{9} \right)\tan^2 \left( \theta \right)  + \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) ^ 2 } } \\
3I &= \int \frac{ \left(  \frac{2}{3} \right) \sec^2 \left( \theta \right) \,\, d\theta  }
 { \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)\sqrt{ \tan ^2 \left( \theta \right)  + 1 } } \\
3I &= \int \frac{ \sec^2 \theta \,\, d\theta } { \sec \theta } \\
3I &= \int \sec \theta \,\, d\theta
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
3I &= \ln{| \sec \theta + \tan \theta |} + C_1 \\
3I &= \ln{| \sqrt{ \tan^2 \theta + 1 } + \tan \theta |} + C_1 \\
3I &= \ln{\Bigg| \sqrt{ \left( \frac{9}{4} \right) u^2 + 1 } + \left( \frac{3}{2}\right) u \Bigg| } + C_1 \\
3I &= \ln{\Bigg| \sqrt{ \left( \frac{9}{4} \right)  \left( x - \frac{1}{3} \right) ^2 + 1 } +
   \left( \frac{3}{2}\right) \left( x - \frac{1}{3} \right)  \Bigg| } + C_1 \\
I &= \left( \frac{1}{3}\right) \ln{\Bigg| \sqrt{ \left( \frac{9}{4} \right)  \left( x - \frac{1}{3} \right) ^2 + 1 } +
   \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)x - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)  \Bigg| } + C \\
%
I &=
 \left( \frac{1}{3}\right) \ln{\Bigg| \sqrt{ \left( \frac{9}{4} \right)
 \left( x^2 - \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) x + \frac{1}{9} \right)  + 1 } +
   \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)x - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)  \Bigg| } + C \\
%
I &=
 \left( \frac{1}{3}\right) \ln{\Bigg| \sqrt{ \left( \frac{9}{4}\right) x^2 - \left( \frac{3}{2} \right) x + \frac{5}{4} } +
   \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)x - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)  \Bigg| } + C \\
I &= \left( \frac{1}{6}\right) \ln{\Bigg| \sqrt{ 9x^2 - 6x + 5 } + 3x - 1  \Bigg| } + C \\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \ln{| \sqrt{9x^2 - 6x + 5} + 3x - 1 |} + C $$

Based upon comments from the group, I updated the last step. My answer is now:
$$ I = \left( \frac{1}{3}\right) \ln{\Bigg| 
\frac{ \sqrt{ 9x^2 - 6x + 5 } + 3x - 1 }{2}  \Bigg| } + C $$
However, this answer is still wrong. I would like to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Why did you half the factor at the front in the last step? It's not necessary to do so.

Comment: @PeterForeman I half the factor in the last step because I  took out a $\frac{1}{2}$ from the square root sign. However, looking at it again that was wrong.

Comment: What you should have is something like$$\frac13\ln{(z/2)}+C_1=\frac13\ln{(z)}+C_2$$where $z=\left|\sqrt{9x^2-6x+5}+3x-1\right|$ and $C_2=C_1-\frac13\ln{(2)}$.

Comment: @PeterForeman I have updated my answer but it is still wrong. I believe my error is not in the last two steps.

Comment: Your error is in the last two steps as I said above. The second to last line is equivalent to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integral fits into the standard form $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}} = \ln|x + \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}| + c$$
Your integral can be rewritten as:
$$I = \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(3x-1)^2 + 4}}$$
Let $3x-1 = t \implies 3dx = dt$
$$I = \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2 + 4}}$$
Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**: As somebody pointed out in the comments, you got the correct answer, but made a mistake in the final few steps.
$$\frac{1}{3}\ln\left| \frac{\sqrt{9x^2 - 6x + 5} + 3x-1}{2}\right| \ne \frac{1}{6}\ln\left|\sqrt{9x^2 - 6x + 5} + 3x-1\right|$$

Comment: I have updated my answer but it is still wrong. I would like to be able to do this problem without using the standard integral you cited. I am hoping that you can tell me where I went wrong. It is true that you found a mistake that I made but it is not the only mistake I made in this problem.

Comment: Your answer is right. You can rewrite it as $$\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|\sqrt{9x^2 - 6x + 5} + 3x-1\right| - \frac{1}{3}\ln(2) + C = \frac{1}{3}\ln\left|\sqrt{9x^2 - 6x + 5} + 3x-1\right| + C'$$, which is the correct answer.